# Django e-commerce cart

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Ссылку на картинку ошибки прикрепил.
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'Cart' object has no attribute 'add'
Ошибка происходит при add to cart.

https://ibb.co/Fz9305n

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

cart.py

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product


class Cart(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        """
        Инициализируем корзину
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # save an empty cart in the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
    """
    Добавить продукт в корзину или обновить его количество.
    """
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                 'price': str(product.price)}
    if update_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
    else:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
    self.save()

def save(self):
    # Обновление сессии cart
    self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
    # Отметить сеанс как "измененный", чтобы убедиться, что он сохранен
    self.session.modified = True

def remove(self, product):
    """
    Удаление товара из корзины.
    """
    product_id = str(product.id)
    if product_id in self.cart:
        del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

def __iter__(self):
    """
    Перебор элементов в корзине и получение продуктов из базы данных.
    """
    product_ids = self.cart.keys()
    # получение объектов product и добавление их в корзину
    products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    for product in products:
        self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

    for item in self.cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
        item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
        yield item

def __len__(self):
    """
    Подсчет всех товаров в корзине.
    """
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def get_total_price(self):
    """
    Подсчет стоимости товаров в корзине.
    """
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in
               self.cart.values())

def clear(self):
    # удаление корзины из сессии
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    self.session.modified = True
```

Comment: это не из Антонио Меле Django 2 в примерах ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/content/glava-7-sozdanie-internet-magazina/sozdanie-proekta-internet-magazina.html делаю вот по этому сайту

Comment: как минимум , если вы не ошиблись в форматировании кода, когда выложили сюда, то методы `add`, `save и т.д. должны быть внутри класса `Cart` на уровне с `def __init__`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin просто лучший))) Не первый раз уже помогаешь ...

Comment: да не за что)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена соблюдением табуляции